# how to make material style set up page

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

As you can see in the picture from the link below, i want to make a same set up screen in this material design style. I have searched the web but can't even find the name of this kind of screen.

Can anyone give me a name of it? or show me some library that provide this kind of screen. thanks in advance!!

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7_w8_KbH7a0/VLcpuwPexsI/AAAAAAAACx4/9zORceLZ5NA/s1600/Screenshot_2014-12-16-03-04-06.png

Comment: Its all about how you design. As answered by @NoobCoder. Make your layout to look like that image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually something that you can implement yourself. In the top, you could place any `ImageView`. In the center, there goes a `RecyclerView` to display a list of wifi networks. And at the bottom, there are 2 buttons (nothing's special about this one).

So, perhaps you could structure your layout like the following

```
LinearLayout (Vertical Orientation)
|_ImageView
|_RecyclerView (0dp height, with layout weight 1)
|_LinearLayout (Horizontal Orientation)
  |_Button
  |_Button
```